# mysql fulltext search doesn't work with some keywords

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search

i have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_variations ON products.id=product_variations.productID
WHERE 
(
    MATCH(products.title, products.metatitle) AGAINST('+ضد*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 OR 
    MATCH(product_variations.title, product_variations.metatitle) AGAINST('+ضد*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
)
```

why this query doesn't find any result with **ضد** keyword but find some results with **ضع** keyword (there is one character difference)

note1: `ft_min_word_len = 2`

note2: there is enough results in database for both keywords

Comment: You need to also check the stop word list used when the index was built.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can i see the stopword list?

Comment: I don't know where the stop words are for your index.  But the place to start is with the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html.

Comment: I wonder if there is an issue with the placement of `+` and `*` due to the text being right-to-left?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the character set and collation of your table, see [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c0d91/3)

Comment: I think the problem is in ft_min_word_len, here it equals 4 and the "+" char is not making any difference ( nothing changes between 2nd and 3rd queries, also it causes an exception in English ), so without the "+", 4 chars are giving the expected results in both arabic and english
see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18ce80/7